# Is Docker slow when using device mapper on Fedora?

Tags: docker, virtualization, boot2docker, device-mapper

I am experimenting docker and I plan to dockerize my project's  CI infratsructure. 
   I am building dockerfiles on 3 different machines: Fedora, Ubuntu, and Boot2Docker (a virtiual machine under windows).

Docker builds on fedora are a lot slower than on the other 2 machines, especially the opration that creates a new image after a Step in the Dockerfile.

So my question is:  Is device mapper a lot slower than AUFS or should I search for some other reason ? Should I expect better if I put in place a RHEL7 config ?

Config1:  fedora 21  (3.18.3-201.fc21.x86_64)

```
sudo docker info
Containers: 27
Images: 1353
Storage Driver: devicemapper
Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Backing Filesystem: extfs                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Data Space Used: 82.77 GB                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Data Space Total: 107.4 GB                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Metadata Space Used: 103.9 MB                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Udev Sync Supported: true                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Library Version: 1.02.93 (2015-01-30)                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Execution Driver: native-0.2                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Kernel Version: 3.18.3-201.fc21.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Operating System: Fedora 21 (Twenty One)                                                                                                                                                                                                     
CPUs: 8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Total Memory: 31.38 GiB
```

Config2: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

```
Containers: 89
Images: 589
Storage Driver: aufs
Backing Filesystem: extfs
Dirperm1 Supported: false
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-49-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 31.38 GiB
```

Config3: Boot2Docker (virtual linux machine running under Windows. docker default solution for Windows)

```
docker info
Containers: 14
Images: 215
Storage Driver: aufs
Backing Filesystem: extfs
Dirperm1 Supported: true
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Kernel Version: 3.18.11-tinycore64
Operating System: Boot2Docker 1.6.0 (TCL 5.4); master : a270c71 - Thu Apr 
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 1.961 GiB
```

I read [this](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2014/09/30/overview-storage-scalability-docker/) article but it still did not help me to clear things out.

Comment: Aufs looks much better than device-mapper according to this test http://sickbits.net/some-docker-performance-tests/

Answer (score 1):

Device Mapper's "slowness" has been documented, especially when used with a loop device.

Here's a useful presentation I found: http://jpetazzo.github.io/assets/2015-03-03-not-so-deep-dive-into-docker-storage-drivers.html.

I would look into overlay.